# How can i get Server Name,ID in XMLA file?

Tags: xmla, ssas-2008

I want to create a Dynamic XMLA file where i want to process the cubes on different servers .

This is the script i have generated from Mangement studio. but i could not able to see the Server node in the XMLA file ( , )

How can i get this from Mangement studio.

Please help thanks,

SSAS_2008_CUBE
        Sales
      
      ProcessFull
      UseExisting

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the server name in the XMLA, you need to connect to the server before running the XMLA, so the script runs against the server that you are connected to.